# .net Core with React - how to return a file and display in new browser tab

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I am trying to retrieve a document from a document warehouse then display that document in a new browser tab.  I am  using .net core 3.1 and react 16.
Here's what i have tried:

```
var link = '/Document/ViewDocument?docId=' + docId
window.open(link, "_blank");
```

This give an Unsupported media type error 415 and the request never hits the controller.

I tried using fetch and returning a filepath but this is restricted in the browser.

```
const response = await fetch('Document/ViewDocument', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ docId: docID })
});
const data = await response.json();   
window.open('file:///' + data, "_blank");  //data = filepath
```

I've also tried fetch and returned a file from the controller but this didn't work either"

Here is my controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ViewDocument")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ViewDocument(int docId)
{
    //There is logic omitted  here that actually retrieves the  document from  the document warehouse by docId.
    string filePath = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\app\\tempfiles\\fileName";
    string contentType = "application/pdf";
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    return File(fs, contentType);
}
```

In .net 4.7 i was able to do this:

```
var link = '@Url.Action("ViewDocument", "Document", new { area = "" })?docId=' + docId;
window.open(link, "_blank");
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to return a file from the controller and display that file  in a new browser tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually does work:

```
var link = '/Document/ViewDocument?docId=' + docId
window.open(link, "_blank");
```

It  didn't appear to be working initially because there was an error  occuring in  the document warehouse api.